# Speech Recognizer Android integrate with camera

Tags: android, android-camera, speech-recognition

I am creating a camera app which will capture image when user say "selfie" . Anyone please help as I dont know how to use speech recognizer. It would be really helpful if you could share the code .

I have athe Idea but I dont know how to integrate it:

1- speech recognizer take input from user.

2- compare it with "selfie" use IF statement if matched capture picture if not toast say again.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);    
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,1); 
startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode);
```

Then override OnActivityResult() method and in if compare match with selfie then call Camera Intent

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==101) {
     ArrayList<String> matches_text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
if(matches_text.get(0).equals("selfie"))
{

Intent cam=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cam,requestcode);
}

else
 {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please try again",LENGTH_LONG).show()
 }
```